# Validate the index i

Tags: java

I am working on a sport of diving programming exercise which stores the score of 7 judges. I created a getScore() method which gets the judge's score from a user.  In the method, I need to get a score from a judge at index-i and validate the index i.

Below is my code. I'm not sure if I am doing right. I'm confused on how to validate the index i.

```
//Get the Score from the User 
public static void getScore(ArrayList<Double> score)
{
    //Scanner object to read the judges' scores
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double next = 0; 
    System.out.println("Enter 7 scores");

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        invalid = true; 

        while (invalid)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the score of judge " + (i + 1));
                double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
                score.add(a);

                if(score.contains(keyboard))
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter a valid score in the range (0-10).");
                    a = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    score.add(a); 
                    invalid = true; 
                }
                else
                {
                    invalid = false; 
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid characters found. Try again");
            }
        }
    }

    int index = highestScore(score);
    int lowIndex = lowestScore(score);
    double sum = sumScore(score, index, lowIndex);
    System.out.println("The sum of scores wihtout min and max scores : " + sum);
    System.out.println("The total diver's score is : " + ((sum * difficulty) * 0.6));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *validate the index i*? what do you want to check?

Comment: `if(score.contains(keyboard))` - what is this supposed to do?  `score` contains `double` values not `Scanner` objects **and** as this is obviously false, then your loop will exit

Comment: _validate the index i_ <-- What does that mean?

Comment: I don't know either. It is stated in the assignment as; 1. Get a score from a judge at index-i make sure to validate the index i. 2. Validate a score. 3. Calculate the total. I think he means to check if a specific index exists?

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove else because anyway you are re-entering if input is invalid
c

```
if(score.contains(keyboard))
{
    System.out.println("Enter a valid score in the range (0-10).");
    a = keyboard.nextDouble();
    score.add(a); 
    invalid = true; 
}
else
{
    invalid = false; 
}
```

to

```
if(a<0||a>10)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a valid score in the range (0-10).");
    a = keyboard.nextDouble();
    score.add(a); 
    if(a=0 && a<=10)
        invalid = false; 
}
```

I am assuming you are checking if input is in range 0-10.

Comment: I guess so. or to check if an ArrayList contains a value.

Comment: `score` is an `ArrayList` - why would it be `<0` ?

Comment: @AbdulSultani you should  be more brief about the questions